# Not Getting Image from ImagePath in IOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, uiimage

[image: Getting imagepath here]

[image: error here] I am getting image from below Image path:

```
Users/Srihari/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D29D4F6F-E146-419D-B4B8-B1914F56569F/data/Containers/Data/Application/637675BB-EFA1-A8RT-8B73-A3628/DocumentsCoverImage.png
```

when try to display image in IOS using below code ,it showing null value

```
 var eventImageEntitys = await _historyService.GetHistoricalEventImagesByTimelineId(ApplicationContext.TimeLineId);

 foreach (var eventImageEntity in eventImageEntitys)
    {
        UIImage image = new UIImage(eventImageEntity.ImagePath);
    }
```

I am getting "image" as null value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to save image name with your image category id

```
    public string GetRelativePath(string categoryId, string imageName)
    {
        return "/Images/" + categoryId + "/" + imageName;
    }
```

this is the way to get sub folder path based on your image category id Xamarin.Ios and finally get full path of that image by passing relativePath of your image

```
    public string GetFullPath(string relativePath)
    {
        return GetPersonalFolder() + relativePath;
    }
```

Initialize your UIImage as

```
    UIImage image = UIImage.FromFile(GetFullPath(imageRelativePath ));
```

Answer (score 0):

iOS sandboxes all applications, therefore you won't be able to access the filesystem like you are. If your image is bundled you can access it by using `UIImage.FromBundle()`.

Using the name of the image as set in **Assets Catalog** use the below code:

`UIImage image = new UIImage.FromBundle("MyImageName");`

Comment: Thanks @Leon Storey , but i am having lot of images.getting from database. it is very difficult to add all those images

Comment: Your question isn't detailed enough, so are you calling a webservice to retrieve this images from a remote database on the device? Is this a sqlite database? I take it that you want to write the image to a file either to cache it, in which case [this might be of help](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_the_file_system/) to write the image to the applications sandbox. Then pass the relative path to `UIImage`.

Comment: i am using sqlite database @Leon Storey

Comment: I am getting the Error like "Could not initialize an instance of the type 'UIKit.UIImage'

Comment: @Prasanthi could you update your question with the modified code?

Comment: I am updating the code @Leon Storey. while running the application it's working fine.but reopen the application it showing null value and getting the above mentioned error

Comment: no @Leon Story ,eventImageEntitys as List in that i am iterating each one

Comment: @Prasanthi You haven't included the code for `_historyService` so can't tell you why `eventImageEntity.ImagePath` is null. I assume the issue is that `_historyService` isn't returning data.

Comment: i am getting data successfully,while initializing image path to uiimage it showing null value

Comment: i am getting image as null value not eventImageEntity.ImagePath

Comment: @Prasanthi Can you give an example result of `eventImageEntity.ImagePath`. For some reason the path isn't accepted by `UIImage` and therefore throwing an error leaving you with a null value. Is `ImagePath` a local or remote path? And does it abide by the sandbox rules and limitations on iOS?

Comment: Getting image path from server and saving locally